# Update Trigger how to delete old record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have created Insert trigger on table A which inserts record in table B whenever insert happens on Table A. This works fine but if I use Update Trigger on table A it inserts the updated record in Table B but does not delete the old record from table B. How to acheive the desired result ?

```
ALTER TRIGGER trigger1 on tableA
FOR UPDATE

AS 
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT C.column1 FROM  tableB C INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON C.column1 = I.column1 WHERE  C.column1 = I.column1 AND C.column2 = I.column2 )
 INSERT INTO tableB ( column1 , column2 )
    SELECT column1 , column2 
    FROM INSERTED I
    WHERE RecordTypeId IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY column1 , column2 
    ORDER BY column1 , column2 

END
```

Comment: Why would you want to delete the earlier version?  An archive table would typically keep all versions of a record.

Comment: It is not like archived table but another table which contains distinct records from table A for some columns

Comment: Well, you would make the trigger delete the old row? What is the question here?

Comment: Edit your question and show the current version of the trigger.  It only needs to check if the row exists first and then delete it.

Comment: read little about inserted and deleted in trigger.how to identify insrted and deleted then construct your script accordingly.

Comment: I already have Delete trigger .. But my guess is as I am only updating the record in table A and not deleting it doesn't fire. Question is how to delete the record from table B which has changed in table A due to updation

Comment: @user3013365 so why don't you update tableB when tablA update occur? Why still attempting to insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check following [SQL Server Update trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-sql-server-trigger-example-to-log-changes-history.aspx) which deletes from target table using the internal **deleted** table

```
create TRIGGER trigger1 on tableA
FOR UPDATE

AS 
BEGIN

 DELETE tableB
 FROM tableB b
 INNER JOIN deleted d
    on b.column1 = d.column1
    and b.column2 = d.column2 


 INSERT INTO tableB ( column1 , column2 )
    SELECT column1 , column2 
    FROM INSERTED
```

Please test before using productive.

Comment: Thanks @Eralper .. Works perferctly